# Steps To Generating Image from OpenWrt SDK

Tags: openwrt

Here's what I have done so far:

make menuconfig :
 Target System (Ralink RT288x/RT305x/RT3883)
 Subtarget (RT3662/RT3883 based boards)
 Target Profile (Sercomm NA900)

Then I ran "make":
ghanem@ghanem-VGN-BZ31XT:~/Documents/openwrtsdk/openwrt$ make

```
 make[1] world
 make[2] target/compile
 make[3] -C target/linux compile
 make[2] package/cleanup
 make[2] package/compile
 make[3] -C package/opkg host-compile
 make[3] -C package/base-files compile
 make[3] -C package/busybox compile
 make[3] -C package/button-hotplug compile
 make[3] -C package/libnl-tiny compile
 make[3] -C package/wireless-tools compile
 make[3] -C package/iw compile
 make[3] -C package/mac80211 compile
 make[3] -C package/crda compile
 make[3] -C package/dnsmasq compile
 make[3] -C package/dropbear compile
 make[3] -C package/e2fsprogs compile
 make[3] -C package/iptables compile
 make[3] -C package/firewall compile
 make[3] -C package/hostapd compile
 make[3] -C package/udevtrigger compile
 make[3] -C package/hotplug2 compile
 make[3] -C package/kernel compile
 make[3] -C package/libgpio compile
 make[3] -C package/libna9xx compile
 make[3] -C package/maccalc compile
 make[3] -C package/mtd compile
 make[3] -C package/na9xx-defcfg compile
 make[3] -C package/zlib compile
 make[3] -C package/na9xx-mtd compile
 make[3] -C package/na9xx-nvram compile
 make[3] -C package/na9xx-rwee compile
 make[3] -C package/libtool compile
 make[3] -C package/opkg compile
 make[3] -C package/linux-atm compile
 make[3] -C package/libpcap compile
 make[3] -C package/ppp compile                                                                                                                                                     
 make[3] -C package/rt2x00ee compile                                                                                                                                                
 make[3] -C package/lua compile                                                                                                                                                     
 make[3] -C package/uci compile                                                                                                                                                     
 make[3] -C package/swconfig compile                                                                                                                                                
 make[2] package/install                                                                                                                                                            
 make[3] -C package/base-files install
 make[3] -C package/busybox install
 make[3] -C package/button-hotplug install
 make[3] -C package/crda install
 make[3] -C package/dnsmasq install
 make[3] -C package/dropbear install
 make[3] -C package/e2fsprogs install
 make[3] -C package/firewall install
 make[3] -C package/hostapd install
 make[3] -C package/hotplug2 install
 make[3] -C package/iptables install
 make[3] -C package/iw install
 make[3] -C package/kernel install
 make[3] -C package/libgpio install
 make[3] -C package/libna9xx install
 make[3] -C package/libnl-tiny install
 make[3] -C package/mac80211 install
 make[3] -C package/maccalc install
 make[3] -C package/mtd install
 make[3] -C package/na9xx-defcfg install
 make[3] -C package/na9xx-mtd install
 make[3] -C package/na9xx-nvram install
 make[3] -C package/na9xx-rwee install
 make[3] -C package/opkg install
 make[3] -C package/ppp install
 make[3] -C package/rt2x00ee install
 make[3] -C package/swconfig install
 make[3] -C package/uci install
 make[3] -C package/udevtrigger install
 make[3] -C package/wireless-tools install
 make[3] -C package/zlib install
 make[2] package/rootfs-prepare
 make[3] package/preconfig
 make[2] target/install
 make[3] -C target/linux install
 make[2] package/index
ghanem@ghanem-VGN-BZ31XT:~/Documents/openwrtsdk/openwrt$
```

Now, I'm stuck because I don't know what's the next step is. So could anybody explain to me what I'm supposed to do next? Thank you.